# How to read clicked link's url on WebView without going new url?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a `Webiew`. I want read clicked link's url but `Webiew` mustn't go this url. WebView must stay same page.

Example: User clicks *"https://stackoverflow.com/questions"* button and app read this link. But WebView must still stay on *"https://stackoverflow.com/"* without refresh. 
I can read clicked link's URL but i can't stop the WebView, it goes to new url.

Comment: use shouldOverrideUrlLoading() override method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Sudheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630837/sudheesh-r) suggest you should extend `WebView` provide an new implementation  of [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).
Is the same case of [Web View onclick event for a specific link in that webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861905/web-view-onclick-event-for-a-specific-link-in-that-webview) .

I think you should avoid to call `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);` to prevent the default behaviour.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(isURLMatching(url)) {
                    openNextActivity();
                    return true;
                }
                //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    protected boolean isURLMatching(String url) {
            // some logic to match the URL would be safe to have here
        return true;
    }

    protected void openNextActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: for other types of links is it ok?

Comment: what was missing?

Comment: I think the missing is on loading time. I changed some action timing.

Comment: please just add the missing part in the comment I will complete my answer for everybody